# concat in postgresql

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, string-concatenation

I created a function using postgresql. But this function returns error when i try to execute it. 
error `"ERROR:  syntax error at or near "||"`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_address_book(address_ids character)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$ 
SET sqlStatement = 'select * from addressbook';
SET address_ids = 'Post' || 'greSQL';
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'sql' STABLE
COST 100;
```

My Server version is 8.3.14. Is this wrong? how do i concat two strings in postgresql?

Comment: Note that using quoted language names `'sql'` or `'plpgsql'`is unsupported and will not work any longer when moving to 9.1 or higher. You should specify the language **without** single quotes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Good advice. But to be precise, [I quote the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html): `For backward compatibility, the name can be enclosed by single quotes.`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: it seems it **will** go away with the next version: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/language-name-case-sensitivity-also-known-as-plpgsql-PLpgSQL-tp5595577.html

Comment: I would love to see strings disallowed for the identifier, and I know they really want to. But I doubt it will happen for 9.3. Too many people would whine about broken code. Check out the [devel manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-createfunction.html). Still the same disclaimer. The case you link to deals with the fact that 'PLpgSQL' no longer works, because *lower casing* has been removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use variables you need a `plpgsql` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_address_book(address_ids character)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare
   sqlStatement text;
   address_ids text;
begin
   sqlStatement := 'select * from addressbook';
   address_ids := 'Post' || 'greSQL';
end
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Comment: Use `LANGUAGE plpgsql` without single quotes. It's an identifier, quoting is discouraged and only tolerated for backward compatibility.

Comment: Upvoted. :) And I took the liberty to remove the redundant `declare` key word.